# The "Best" Blunt Weapon?

Tags: weapons, medieval

So there is a humanoid creature 9 feet (2,75 meters) tall, about 1000 pounds (about 450 kg), and 10 times the strength of even the strongest men. What would be the best *one-handed*, blunt weapon for him to use assuming he primarily fights regular-sized humans in small groups?

Comment: Why is the [tag:magic] tag on this question? You’ve defined no features of a developed magic system that would have any bearing on which weapon would be the best. As it stands, this question is pretty broad and could do with some more restrictions to get better answers. I’d recommend maintaining a draft in the Sandbox for the time being to get better advice on what needs work so we can answer this better: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions

Comment: the best blunt weapons is always the one that apply largest force over largest possible area in the quickest time.

Comment: @SZCZERZO KŁY: Those are mutually exclusive. The smaller the area the larger the force - and the heavier a weapon the larger the force, but the slower the blow is.

Comment: @Daniel that's was joke comment that for best blunt weapons making this trifecta is the best. Otherwise you end up with slash/thrust weapon because it will be better.

Comment: @SZCZERZO KŁY: Ok, didn´t get that - my bad ... thou shalt not use irony on the internets for it is lost on the fools out there?

Comment: He has a BMI of 62 so approximately spherical in spite of his strength, choice of weapon should take that into account.

Comment: @Daniel Poe law is against me but I won't stop using language I have master in.

Comment: I should have clarified, he is proportioned much like someone such as Hafthor Bjornsen but is very dense and i didnt mean to add the magic tag but meant to add fantasy, my bad.

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it. That being said, I don't see a problem here. We've accepted this type of question several times before.

Comment: The truth. There's nothing more damaging.

Comment: Well i suppose crushing the mind is just as important as crushing the body lol

Answer (score 4):

A mace, preferably the leftmost one in the picture below - given the strength of the creature the blunt force should be enough to shatter anything.

All the added bells an whistles on the other maces would increase the chance of getting stuck in an enemies armor or braking/bending under the impact. That would needlessly slow you down when already having enough destructive force. You main concern will be getting swarmed so you need to shift targets quickly

You also would want to make the weapon rather short against *regular-sized humans in small groups*. If the weapon gets too long it would risk being under-run and unable to act effectively in close quarts. The usual reason for longer weapons do not apply when you are able to shatter any defenses or polearms of your enemies with the flick of a wrist and already have a 50% greater reach.

On anything made of wood the handle would probably shatter after a few blows - given that the creature and thus his hands and the weapons handle are only 50% bigger than a normal human but he has 10x the strength.

*Best counter tactic for the humans: Swarm out and attack with ranged weapons or attack with short sword/daggers, surround him and get really close really quick.*

[image: Picture of maces]
*(By Samuraiantiqueworld - Own work, [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=27716680))*

Comment: Yeah, one handed blunt weapon pretty much is a mace by definition.

Comment: @VilleNiemi good point. Nevertheless, this answer could be improved by suggesting specifics. For example a 10x stronger man could wield a heavier longer mace than usual, and a 9' man wouldn't want to have to stoop to strike at, or defend against, the more normally proportioned. That might be relevant. He might also want to be able to operate in very close quarters - in what manner would one of, or a combination of several of, those maces offer this?

Comment: @Grimm The Opiner: thanks for the suggestions, tried to improve on the points you mentioned.

Comment: I've been thinking of some ways to counter such tactics such as adding more armor plating on him and giving him a large shield and some good solid boots for kicking the pesky humans

Answer (score 2):

In battle or in arenas where a gladiator or warrior is used to fighting often, tactics involving protection and maintaining distance are paramount for repeated victory.  Assuming he could get his hands on any equipment, he'd likely favor a long-range weapon that is unobtrusive and a medium-to-short range weapon that still allows him distance without getting hurt.

For the long-range weapon, assuming there are pistols and rifles, a pistol would likely be an excellent compromise.  Kept loaded and ready, he'd likely favor the pistol because it is light and he could get in a shot before having to switch to his medium-to-short range weapon.  He probably would not put much stock into being able to reload it in time for a second shot, meaning he'd load it prior to battle and fire it once before close range fighting.

Against smaller "normal" humans, a polearm would almost certainly allow him to inflict serious blows while keeping his distance.  One of the disadvantages to the polearm is that it is slow, but my guess is that with superior strength, he can more than makeup for that disadvantage.  It has also the considerable advantage that against multiple fighters, a single fast pass can at least destabilize the fighters, but far more likely that they would immediately sustain injuries, armor or not.  He could maintain a distance which would otherwise not be possible at close range by using swords or daggers.

Other short-to-medium ranged weapons would be likely equally suited, as they all depend on maintaining a reasonable distance, but would be difficult to use without significant strength and size.  These include the flail, scythe and lance (though the latter may be less useful against multiple fighters).

Answer (score 1):

I think any king of fighting stick will work very well, like the ones used in escrima or kali. Better if it is all steel.

[image]

Basically, your "giant" hits with so much strength, that any blow would cause broken bones even with a good padded armor.

So he just needs his weapon to be durable (with his height, he'll hit a lot of helmets and push out of his way another weapons), fast (because he is fighting groups) and with a better reach than a one handed mace (because his enemy will probably use spears and halberds against him, so your humanoid will need to take advantage of his longer arms).

Bonus point: sticks can be thrown quite well (there is even a hunting technique based on breaking the legs of your prey by throwing sticks at it and the boomerang was born like this). This will help your "giant" against archers, javelineers, horseriders and, of course, annoying shepherds with a sling.

Answer (score 1):

A War Hammer would be nice. It allows you to use either the blunt or the pointy side, or even grapple, depending of your needs. With his superior force, your guy could unbalance a foe by grappling his shield, then take a strike in the opening.

Answer (score 0):

Against who ? 
Against another one like himself or against a normal human ?
Against a normal human he can use whatever he want, just the impact force will kill the human (or at least make seriuous damages) so even a little tree (for him) can do the kill.

Against another of his own kind, you are back to a human-human like fight (even if bigger scale), so the "rules" for humans apply, I'd say a sword for duel and a bow for long range shots.

Comment: I’m hesitant to upvote this since it’s really more of a comment on the question’s premise, but you do bring up some good points.

Answer (score -1):

### Ball and Chain

At 20 kg (44 lbs) or more, it allows your creature to put all of it's great strength to work.

Attached to a chain, it also allows the creature's whole 9 feet, plus maybe another two feet of chain length (11ft / 3.3m total) to be put into multiplying the creatures great strength $ v = \sqrt { 2 \times length \times acceleration } $

A chain also can be accelerated faster than a solid rod because you don't have to put your whole body into it. If the average strength of a human is (100kg x 1 gee acceleration = 1kN), then your creature's strength is 10kN. Then the acceleration on a 20kg ball is around 500 m/s/s. Using the velocity equation, is about 57 meters per second. Convert that into kinetic energy with $ E = {1\over2} mass \times velocity^2 $ = 60 kJ, or roughly the impacting power of a car at 20 miles per hour. And that's without a good wind-up.

[image]

By contrast, with a solid weapon, your creature's whole body weight is put into the swing. This works against it in the velocity component, only allowing about 2 m/s on a good swing (roughly equivalent to what a human would do). On the other hand, most of the 1,000 pounds of the creature's body weight is keeping the solid weapon moving. Net is roughly 2 kJ.

With the chain, you can sweep large groups of people at once. Also, since the weapon doesn't require any high degree of craftsmanship, it's cheap and easy to produce or replace.

Comment: Oh dear!! First, that image isn't a weapon, it's a restraint. Second, there's no weapon called a ball and chain. There were flails, and the chain was often surprisingly short. Your physics is complete baloney. You might be able to salvage this answer by pivoting to making the case for a flail.

Comment: Grimm, I'm not sure where you're coming from. Is this sarcasm, or do you really not recognize a swinging heavy weight could hurt people? Official Medieval Weaponry was not a requirement of the original post,  and I'll check but I don't think the medieval tag implies it either. The questioner is asking for a weapon for a creature ten times as strong and nearly twice as tall as an average adult. As to the physics : s = .5 at^2 + vt; v = at. Solve for v in terms of s: t = v/a. Sub into position equation - s = .5 a (v/a)^2. Reduce: s = .5 v^2 / a. Solve for v: v^2 = 2sa; v = sqrt(2sa).

Comment: You've overestimated human strength by a factor of 10. Your final speed of the ball seems to be based on accelerating it over the height of the humanoid, which isn't how the ball is accelerated at all - it's done by centripetal force. No clue what you're getting at with the last paragraph about chain vs. solid weapon.

Comment: The original post asks for weapons for a creature with ten times the strength of a human. As for human strength, being able to lift what I think is a reasonable for someone physically active 100kg (220 lbs) is 100kg x 10 m/s/s in gravity = 1,000N, or 1kN for the human (10kN for the questioner's ten times human strength creature). As for the centripedal force, it's being provided by the creature.

Answer (score -1):

**Caber.**

[image: caber]
https://www.scotland.com/blog/caber-toss-scotland/

1. Keeps smaller enemies at a distance via sweeping action.
2. Offers a field effect - the entire length of the caber.
3. Cannot get tangled.
4. Offers a method to retain kinetic energy.  A mace you have to stop with muscle power or follow through and hit the ground.  The caber you can keep spinning 360 degrees as you advance - like a claymore sword.
5. A greenwood caber would be unlikely to break.
6. Easy to replace your greenwood caber if you have access to a forest.
7. If you are feeling mean, don't trim the branches off your greenwood caber down to such smoothness.

Comment: This doesn't really look like a one-handed weapon, even for someone 9 feet tall. Actually, it doesn't really look like a weapon at all. Why specifically go for "caber" instead of "big stick"? Not sure how you keep this thing spinning 360 degrees, unless you're doing it over your head, which give plenty of clearance for average-sized people.

Comment: You could make a case for using a tree trunk (thin enough - or shaped - to be grasped one handed) but a caber is not that. Again, if you pivot to explaining why waving a big lump of wood is a good idea you might be able to salvage something here.

Comment: @Nuclear Wang:  A caber is already the right size for a 9 foot tall giant to use it as a [long staff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarterstaff) which is roughly double the height of its user.  I called it a caber instead of a "giant sized long staff" because there are images readily available to show how big a caber is, which gives an idea of the effect it would have against normal sized humans.  Re "not sure" - you can spin a staff around your body along many different axes.  At a high school football game you will see the color guard spin flag on staffs around their waists.